# Objects made with geometry nodes don't stick to the base

Tags: geometry-nodes, weight-painting

I'm trying to create a lot of beads on the base, but they appear around the base and not touching it. At first I didn't bother since I hadn't done the weight paint at the moment, but after doing it, they are still appearing around the base and none or them is detecting the weight paint.
I even watched again the tutorial I saw when doing my first donut, but I have everything as the tutorial and I can't find what's the problem is.
Also tried creating a plane in case the base was the problem, but with the plane the beads were appearing around it too.
What could be the problem here?
[image: Beads]
[image: Weight paint]
[image]

The blend file above. I deleted the main model since it isn't the problem.
I could almost fix the problem by setting the origin to geometry (beads) for some reason it didn't work before. But the beads don't detect the weight paint yet.

Also if possible I would like to know why my flower ribbons have an exorbitant amount of vertices. I just noticed that without them I had 700k vertices and with all of them I have more than 2 million. (I first made the first triangle and after that I used the "shift + D" in edit mode to create 7 more triangles inside the same object) just in case it is important to know how I made the flowers.

Comment: This seems to me to be a problem with the scaling of the objects. What happens if you select the option *Relative* in the node `Object Info`?

Comment: @quellenform nothing. They don't change their position, rotation nor their color

Comment: Then please check the scaling of your objects or share your blend file with us.

Comment: @quellenform I added the file. Also if it isn't a bother, I would like to know if there is a solution for the vertex problem I said at the end.